ffmpeg.wasm DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at '<URL>/814.ffmpeg.js' cannot be accessed from origin '<URL>'
I have written a google chrome extension using local ffmpegwasm files (no need to run a server or download any ffmpegwasm files), which allows users to click an injected 'download' button under Reddit videos (via content_scripts). This was working great on ffmpegwasm v11, but since migrating to v12 (latest version) I have been unable to solve the following exception which is triggered during ffmpeg.load(): as seen in chrome's console log:
DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'https://www.redditstatic.com/814.ffmpeg.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'https://reddit.com'. At i.load (chrome-extension://ljejfmmefhnpbpdhkhbbajpihfhnbdnm/lib/ffmpeg/umd/ffmpeg.js:1:2918)

I'm a programming beginner and I've been stuck trying to fix this for many, many hours. This exception does not happen and the video downloads if I instead use a feature of my extension which allows entering a Reddit video URL directly into a field in the extensions popup or options window. Also, I have no idea why the 814.ffmpeg.js file is being referenced along with redditstatic.com (from exception to exception, this url seems to randomly change to other reddit url's too), though I imagine this is part of the problem?
I have seen there are a couple of mentions of this error on the ffmpegwasm github repository, with some fixes involving using the worker814URL and/or classWorkerURL params within ffmpeg.load() and pointing them to the 814.ffmpeg.js file, which I have tried without any success (although I did notice that using classWorkerURL changed https://www.redditstatic.com/814.ffmpeg.js to chrome-extension://ljejfmmefhnpbpdhkhbbajpihfhnbdnm/lib/ffmpeg/umd/814.ffmpeg.js). Though, It seems that previous discussions around this error might not be too helpful for me as those appear geared towards ffmpegwasm running with a server, as apposed to entirely locally within a chrome extension.
Any help would be super appreciated - many thanks

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
